# Turn on occlusion with lines for mesh in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, lidar

I would like to display a mesh with iOS ARKit with SceneKit and not RealityKit.

I am able to add a material to the mesh, like so which displays the mesh just fine

```
let edgesMaterial = SCNMaterial()
edgesMaterial.fillMode = .lines
edgesMaterial.lightingModel = .constant
edgesMaterial.transparency = 1.0
edgesMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
scnGeom.materials = [edgesMaterial]
```

However, this adds overlapping lines of the wireframes in the scene. With RealityKit the fix is rather simple by just adding

```
arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
```

How can I get the same effect with a scenekit scene? Basically I want to add a occlusion material with lines. Any pointers?

**UPDATE:**

I can get something close but not quite the same visualization by using this:

```
sceneView.debugOptions.insert([.showWireframe])
let occMaterial = SCNMaterial()
occMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0)
scnGeom.materials = [occMaterial]
```

The lines appear white and also any object I place in the scene will render the wireframe automatically now with this